# Jmeter Error in non GUI mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm getting this error but I'm not aware of me using any plugins...What can I do to fix this?

[root@centos6 bin]# ./jmeter -n -t ../scripts/Beta/Beta_Load_Test_Plan1.jmx

```
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/opt/jmeter/bin/../scripts/Beta/Beta_Load_Test_Plan1.jmx', conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
---- Debugging information ----
message             : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[8]/kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
line number         : 16279
------------------------------- : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
---- Debugging information ----
message             : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[8]/kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
line number         : 16279
-------------------------------
message             : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
---- Debugging information ----
message             : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[8]/kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
line number         : 16279
-------------------------------
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[8]/kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
line number         : 16279
version             : 2.13 r1665067
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5):

It fails at [DummySampler](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/) - part of ["standard" jmeter-plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/StandardSet/):

> conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler

So download JMeterPlugins-Standard from [here](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/), unzip its contents to JMeter installation directory, restart JMeter.

Comment: I only see plugins manager to download there! Is that what you are talking about? I have downloaded it and copied the jar in lib folder. I have looked at other channels also, but I don't find this "standard jmeter plugin". Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

From this side [jpgc-dummy](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-dummy) download 0.2.zip and just copy jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.3 to your jmeter\lib directory.